# angularjs ie8 scope variable not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an app that makes and api call in angularjs and put the results on the page. It works perfectly with all modern browser, but is failing with ie8.  Looking more closely at the code, I can see that the data is coming back, but the scope variable never gets updated. I am using the angular-ie8 script:  https://github.com/fergaldoyle/angular.js-ie8-builds
This is the code I have for ie8 in my controller

```
if (LSConfigValues.IsLegacyBrowser) {
    $http({url:  LSConfigValues.ApiEndPoint,
        params:{'X-LS-Auth-Token': LSConfigValues.Token,id: $routeParams.categoryId ,paginateResults: false,sort:'sortorder',username:LSConfigValues.Username,url:'/api/assetListings/getvolumesbycategoryid'}
}).success(
    function (data) {

        //this output the correct number of volumes in ie8
        alert(data.volumes);

        //for some reason this never gets updated in ie8
        $scope.tiles = data.volumes;
```

And I have this in my html

```
<div ng-app="learnApp" ng-controller="learnTilesController">
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Categories.cshtml", category)
<--this value is not getting updated in ie8
<input type="text" ng-model="tiles.length" />
```

Any idea why this variable is not getting updated? I'm banging my head against the wall trying to find a solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you need Angular 1.3+? If not, stick to 1.2 if you must support IE8.

Comment: Just noticed each time the data loads I get the error message   TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method, but not sure which object it is referring to...